# How to validate PHP in VS code using WSL php

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In VS code you can validate php using php executable. But is there a way to use php installed on WSL instead?

Answer (score 13):

What worked for me:

Create php.bat  file:

```
@echo off
set v_params=%*
set v_params=%v_params:\=/%
set v_params=%v_params:c:=/mnt/c%
set v_params=%v_params:"=\"%
@bash -c "php %v_params%"
```

put it in C:\WSL-Tools\php.bat

Then, in VScode settings (Ctrl+comma):

`"php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\WSL-Tools\\php.bat"`

And it works.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible with an old school batch-file.

php.bat

```
@echo off
c:\windows\sysnative\bash.exe -c "php %*"`
```

setting.json

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "c:\\PATH_TO\\php.bat"
```

Comment: For php.bat, replace "sysnative" with "system32" and remove the ` from the end of the string.

Comment: Perfect answer, however the bat file would be great as:  

`bash.exe -c "php %*"`

Instead of: 

c:\windows\sysnative\bash.exe -c "php %*"`

Answer (score 3):

The other answer did not work for me neither: after some work I came up with these two scripts:

This one is called `php.bat` and I placed it in `C:\wsl-tools\`:

```
@echo OFF
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem Collect the arguments and replace:
rem  '\' with '/'
rem  'c:' with 'mnt/c'
rem  '"' with '\"'
set v_params=%*
set v_params=%v_params:\=/%
set v_params=%v_params:C:=/mnt/c%
set v_params=%v_params%
set v_params=%v_params:"=\"%

rem Call the windows-php inside WSL.
rem windows-php is just a script which passes the arguments onto
rem the original php executable and converts its output from UNIX
rem syntax to Windows syntax.
C:\Windows\sysnative\bash.exe -l -c "windows-php %v_params%"
```

This one is called windows-php and is placed somewhere in the WSL path (i chose `/usr/local/bin`).

```sh
# Pass all the arguments to PHP.
output=$(php "$@")
# Perform UNIX->WINDOWS syntax replacements.
output="${output//$'\n'/$'\r'$'\n'}"
output="${output//\/mnt\/c/C:}"
output="${output//\//\\}"
# Echo corrected output.
echo $output
```

Setting `"php.validate.executablePath": "c:\\wsl-tools\\php.bat"` works for me.

**Note**:

You might want to follow [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22391) and [this pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/25576) as it looks like this problem is going to be officially addressed in one of the next releases.

Comment: For the x64 version of Visual Studio Code you have to change the first script's last line to:
C:\Windows\system32\bash.exe -l -c "windows-php %v_params%"

Comment: `C:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe "windows-php %v_params%"` since bash.exe is deprecated this is the new way to go

Comment: Could be something unique with Alpine, but I had to do `output=$(eval "php $@")` or it would take "/mnt/c/some/path" and try and parse the quotes as part of the path.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not too late this is the way to go with ubuntu 20.04 WSL 2

```
@echo OFF
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

rem Collect the arguments and replace:
rem  '\' with '/'
rem  'c:' with 'mnt/c'
rem  '"' with '\"'
set v_params=%*
IF DEFINED v_params (
    set v_params=%v_params:\=/%
    set v_params=%v_params:C:=/mnt/c%
    set v_params=%v_params%
    set v_params=%v_params:"=\"%
)
rem Call the windows-php inside WSL.
rem windows-php is just a script which passes the arguments onto
rem the original php executable and converts its output from UNIX
rem syntax to Windows syntax.
@wsl.exe -d Ubuntu-20.04 -- php %v_params%
```

By Placing this php.bat in

> c:/wsl-plugins/

You don't need to do WSL bit.